# Render numbers for tick on a WPF Slider using TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, slider

There have been several earlier questions related to adding number values to the ticks on a WPF `Slider` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289322/wpf-silverlight-slider-control-display-tick-numbers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329916/wpf-how-to-set-a-dynamic-range-of-numbers-for-vertical-slider)). All proposed solutions I have found so far are to do with inheriting from the `TickBar` class and then using `DrawText(FormattedText text, Point point)` to draw the value. Something like:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
   foreach(double tick in Ticks)
   {
      formattedText = new FormattedText(Convert.ToString(tick),
                                       CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                                       FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                       new Typeface("Verdana"), // I don't know why all examples use the Verdana font :P
                                       10, Brushes.Black);
      dc.DrawText(formattedText, ComputeTheRightPosition(tick));
   }
}
```

While this is a valid solution, I am finding that it is not generic enough for me, due to the `FormattedText`. In my application, the `Style` can change at runtime, so I would prefer a way of putting all the numbers in a `TextBlock` or something, which can dynamically update its style and font and all.

Is it possible to add text boxes in this way in an`Slider` or `TickBar` subclass?

Comment: You can add whatever you like if you provide a new `ControlTemplate` for it.

Comment: it's unfortunate that `TickBar` is not a Control, so we cannot use any Template for it. Unless you modify the template of the Slider itself and replace the TickBar with your custom TickBar.

Comment: This seems exactly the problem: I cannot make a control template for `TickBar`. @KingKing: do you know of an example that does what you suggest? Cause I can't find any example or explanation of how to modify a Template of a `TickBar` at all, let alone how to modify the tick so they're shown in text boxes.

Comment: Sorry I have not created any custom TickBar (I've almost satisfied with the default tickbar). You can either create some custom class inheriting from `TickBar` or replace the TickBar (in the Template of the Slider) with some other control. I would use the `ItemsControl`, then bind the `ItemsSource` to the `Ticks` collection of the `Slider`. You need a Convert to convert that DoubleCollection to such as a TextBox collection. Normally this TextBox collection will be renewed everytime the Ticks collection changes. Anyway doing something like this will have some poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box solution -

Put a canvas above the slider. When slider value changes, get a ratio of value / (max-min)

Use the same ratio to place the textblock in the canvas using SetLeft or Render Transform.